# Generic atomic channel that will work with custom structs as well

Tags: c, generics, atomic

This question is all about [stdatomic.h](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic).

Say, I want some mechanism that allows me to create atomic "channels" with any kind of data, including custom `struct`s. I imagine something like:

```
struct chan {
  atomic_intptr_t ptr;
};
```

The idea is to have `_Atomic intptr_t` capable to hold reference to literally any kind of data.

Then let's image I have custom data...

```
struct person {
  char * name;
};
```

...and I publish it over my atomic channel:

```
struct person bob = {
    .name = "Bob"
};

struct person alice = {
    .name = "Alice"
};

struct chan c = {
    .ptr = &bob
};
```

Given that, the following code is one of many ways I might push new data to my channel:

```
atomic_exchange(&c.ptr, &alice);
```

It works, yet `gcc` warns me:

> warning: initialization of ‘atomic_intptr_t’ {aka ‘long int’} from ‘struct person *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

So it feels that I've taken wrong approach.

What's the better way to have generic channel capable to exchange atomically any kind of data? Can `_Generic` help here?

Comment: @selbie I don’t do C++ if you mean atomic template.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov - Oops, you are right. My bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointers can also be declared `_Atomic`, so I think what you want here is simply a `void *` which is atomic.  (Maybe you're being misled by the lack of a [convenience typedef](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) for this, but it works fine, and atomic pointers are lock-free on most common platforms.)  Thus:

```
#include <stdatomic.h>
struct chan {
    void * _Atomic ptr;
} c;

struct person {
  char * name;
} alice;

int some_integer = 8;

void add_some_stuff(void) {
    atomic_exchange(&c.ptr, &alice);
    // ...
    atomic_exchange(&c.ptr, &some_integer);
    // ...
    atomic_exchange(&c.ptr, NULL);
}
```

[See on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nxjhfo)

Comment: I didn’t know it works with raw pointer as well. Makes sense though. Thanks!